# How do GBR trees differ from random forests regression in terms of predictive performance?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, inference

Is there a case when one would use gradient boosted regression trees instead of random forests regression (or vice versa)?

It appears gradient boosted regression trees have done far better in several ML competitions. However, random forests regression normally works exceptionally well for virtually any problem.

Are there any hard numbers regarding the performance between these two algorithms? Predictive performance? Execution performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparison of random forests, boosting and support vector machines for genomic selection
http://bmcproc.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1753-6561-5-S3-S11

A comparison of stochastic gradient boosting, generalized
additive models, and tree-based methods
http://www.fs.fed.us/rm/pubs_other/rmrs_2006_moisen_g002.pdf

Comment: As it is, this is more of a comment than an answer. It would be much more helpful to include a short summary of the pages you link to, and it would also help combat link rot